# Run after jQuery version selection is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out if a user supports jQuery 2.x
This works fine, but when I try to run a script it doesn't work because jQuery isn't done loading...

How can I trigger `__run()` after jQuery is done loading.

Init script:

```
function __run(){
    //
    // function runs the jQuery website
    //  
    $("body").append( "<p>Test</p>" );
}

(function () {
    var s, s0, js;
    if (typeof JSON !== 'undefined' && 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window) {
        js = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js';
    } else {
        js = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
        alert('Woow, that\'s one old browser, maybe you should upgrade. We don\'t support this version, you can try to use the website though');
    }
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = js;
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s0);
    __run();
}());
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with javascript? it's much easier to handle this using conditional comments since IE is the only browser affected.

Comment: Good question, haha, for that reason actually, to have old-browser-people update their browser... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
(function () {
    var s, s0, js;
    if (typeof JSON !== 'undefined' && 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window) {
        js = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js';
    } else {
        js = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
        alert('Woow, that\'s one old browser, maybe you should upgrade. We don\'t support this version, you can try to use the website though');
    }
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = js;
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s0);

    s.onreadystatechange= function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') __run();
    }
    s.onload= __run;
}());
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the inline `__run()` call before your readystatechange handler.

Comment: Yep, just removed the `__run()` problem solved. Awesome guys!

Comment: Why are you using both onreadystatechange and onload ? Actually in your code, you are calling __run() 3 times, no?!

Answer (score 2):

Check with `onreadystatechange`

```
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
    this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {

         __run();
    }
};
```